# Adding complete between execution of two following lines swift

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode7

need to add complete between the execution of two lines in a(same) function. Is there is any favorable options to do this?

eg:

```
line 1: [executing first operation];

line 2: Complete first operation

line 3: when first operation is compeleted -> [executing second operation];
```

Any help is appreciable. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Use Closure for this type of execution. Reference Link : http://www.learnswift.io/blog/2014/6/9/writing-completion-blocks-with-closures-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

You can use closures for that. Checkout [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)

### Implementation

Here you have the code for declaring your functions.

Let's say that the **first operation** is a function that executes instructions on background thread (i.e we make a network request and we wait for the response. We wait for it to get our data, so we use a `completionHandler`, which is a closure, that is going to be called when our instructions on the **first operation** finish.

Calling upon **first operation**, we are going to get a callback which will be executed when the instructions for the **first operation** finish. When it does return `finished` true, then we are good to go and call second operation.

#### Declaration

```
// First operation
func foo1(completionHandler: (finished: Bool) -> Void) {
    // Considering that you are doing background stuff inside a block
    let foo1Block = {
        // Your instructions
        //....
        
        // When finished
        completionHandler(finished: true)
    }
    
    // Execute block
    foo1Block()
}

// Second operation
func foo2() {
   // Your instructions
}
```

Here is how you call it:

#### Execution

```
foo1 { (finished) -> Void in
    if (finished) {
        // If the first operation is finished let's execute the next one
        self.foo2()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dispatch_group for this. You don't have to wait and its much simpler. Assume that you have a function startFunction() and endFunction() which represents your line and line 3 you can do this. This is a sample of what you can do.

In this example the startFunction() is called and then the endFunction will be called automatically when you press a button.The startFunction enters a dispatch_group but the group is exited only when a button is pressed. I have done this to simulate that the async nature of the solution. You can tweak it as per your needs.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let dg = dispatch_group_create()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    startFunction()
    dispatch_group_notify(dg, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.endFunction()
    }
}

func endFunction() {
    print("endFunction")
}
func startFunction() {
    dispatch_group_enter(dg)
    print("startFunction")
}

@IBAction func buttonAction(sender:UIButton) {
    dispatch_group_leave(dg)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Basically you use a dispatch group and enter that group and do your functions. Then after that you leave the group. You also use dispatch_notify to execute a block when all the code that has called dispatch_group_enter has called left the dispatch group.